# Sqlite Query with Subquery returns empty

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In my app, i'm using subquerys of sqlite, the subquery returns 3 values, its ok, but in the main query, returns empty and i need help in this.

*some parts of variables is in portuguese because i'm brazilian.

```
public List<Table_Anuncio_Empregador> getAllUser_Empregador() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    List<Table_Anuncio_Empregador> anuncios = new ArrayList<Table_Anuncio_Empregador>();

    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("user_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int user_id = preferences.getInt("user_id_conectado",0);

    String selectQuery = "SELECT "+KEY_ID+", "+KEY_IMAGEM_ANUNCIO+", "+KEY_TITULO+", "+KEY_DESCRICAO+", "+KEY_CIDADE
                        + " FROM " + TABLE_ANUNCIO_EMPREGADOR
                        + " WHERE "+ KEY_ID +" IN (SELECT "+KEY_ANUNCIO_EMPREGADOR_ID+" FROM "+ TABLE_ANUNCIO
                        +" WHERE "+ KEY_ANUNCIO_PERFIL+" = 'empregador' AND "+ KEY_USER_ID+" = "+user_id+")";
    Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Table_Anuncio_Empregador anuncio = new Table_Anuncio_Empregador();
            anuncio.setAnuncio_empregador_id(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
            anuncio.setImagem_do_anuncio(c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_IMAGEM_ANUNCIO)));
            anuncio.setTitulo(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TITULO)));
            anuncio.setDescricao(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DESCRICAO)));
            anuncio.setCidade(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CIDADE)));

            anuncios.add(anuncio);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    return anuncios;
}
```

The LOG shows the query as :-

```
E/Banco_Helper: SELECT ID, Imagem_anuncio, Titulo, Descricao, Cidade FROM Anuncio_empregador WHERE ID IN (SELECT Anuncio_empregado_info_ID FROM Anuncio WHERE Anuncio_perfil = 'empregador' AND User_ID = 2)
```

The tables are created using :-

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ANUNCIO =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_ANUNCIO + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                KEY_USER_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                KEY_ANUNCIO_PERFIL + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                KEY_ANUNCIO_EMPREGADOR_ID + " INTEGER," +
                KEY_ANUNCIO_PRESTADOR_ID + " INTEGER," +

                KEY_CREATED_AT + " DATETIME NOT NULL" + ")";
```

and :-

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ANUNCIO_EMPREGADOR =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_ANUNCIO_EMPREGADOR + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                KEY_TITULO + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                KEY_DESCRICAO + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                KEY_BAIRRO + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                KEY_CIDADE + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                KEY_ESTADO + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                KEY_LOCAL_SERVICO + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                KEY_EXIGENCIAS + " TEXT," +
                KEY_IMAGEM_ANUNCIO + " BLOB NOT NULL" + ")";
```

Equating to :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Anuncio( 
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    USER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Anuncio_perfil TEXT NOT NULL,
    Anuncio_empregado_info_ID INTEGER,
    ANUNCIO_PRESTADOR_ID INTEGER,
    CREATED_AT DATETIME NOT NULL
);
```

And :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Anuncio_empregador (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Titulo TEXT NOT NULL,
    Descricao TEXT NOT NULL,
    Bairro TEXT NOT NULL,
    Cidade TEXT NOT NULL,
    Estado TEXT NOT NULL,
    Local_Servico TEXT NOT NULL,
    Exigencias TEXT,
    Imagem_anuncio BLOB NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: somes tutorials of sqlites , switch the IN for = ,
but for me it's the same.

Comment: Are you sure that your subquery returns non-empty values?

Comment: @MenukaIshan , sorry for that, is the query with subquery.

Comment: I was talking about this part in the log. (SELECT Anuncio_empregado_info_ID FROM Anuncio WHERE Anuncio_perfil = 'empregador' AND User_ID = 2)

Comment: Can you run above query in SQLite and check whether it gives a result or not? Possible cause could be that query returning an empty result set

Comment: @MenukaIshan, the subquery is OK, have 3 results, the problem is in the main query, but i don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: your query is syntactically correct. Are you sure that table Anuncio_empregador have relevant ID values to subquery? Can you post those two tables?

Comment: @Menukalshan, where is the code of tables, and code in aplication: https://shrib.com/#T5X1tcgpbgYQAc1fWTJh (stackoverflow does not let me edit the post with too much code)

Comment: @LucasMatheus please read and provide a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As your query appears to be sound and the issue is very likely in the actual data itself. Thus without example data it is very likely that the question will be closed, as it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: basically, i create ANUNCIO for the tables ANUNCIO_EMPREGADOR and ANUNCIO_PRESTADOR but i dont set the values of ids, the column Anuncio_Perfil is the key to know the exactly table, after, the updateanuncio give for the table value of id, because i create the anuncio_empregador after the anuncio

Comment: @MikeT, sorry for this, i'm new in the site

Comment: @LucasMatheus try using a tool to copy the database and open it in that (e.g. DB Browser for SQlite (free), Navicat (free for trial period) and there are others ). You copy the file (in Android Studio click the Device File Explorer goto to data/data/<your package>/database and the file will be the same name as your database). you can then view the data, run queries and so on).

Comment: @MikeT, thanks mike, and thanks Menukalshan , the problem is in method update, i will work in the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your issue is with the actual data rather then the query.

That is, the following was used to create and populate the two tables and to also run the query (plus some intermediate queries). The result was that the three expected rows were included and that the three rows that should have been excluded were. That is **the query in question ran with the expected results**.

The following SQL was used :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Anuncio;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Anuncio( 
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    USER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Anuncio_perfil TEXT NOT NULL,
    Anuncio_empregado_info_ID INTEGER,
    ANUNCIO_PRESTADOR_ID INTEGER,
    CREATED_AT DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Anuncio_empregador;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Anuncio_empregador (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Titulo TEXT NOT NULL,
    Descricao TEXT NOT NULL,
    Bairro TEXT NOT NULL,
    Cidade TEXT NOT NULL,
    Estado TEXT NOT NULL,
    Local_Servico TEXT NOT NULL,
    Exigencias TEXT,
    Imagem_anuncio BLOB NOT NULL DEFAULT X'00010203040506070809'
)
;   

INSERT INTO Anuncio_empregador 
    (Titulo,Descricao,Bairro,Cidade,Estado,Local_Servico,Exigencias)
    VALUES
        ('Mr','Albert','Bloggs','something','something else','xxx','xxxx'),
        ('Mr','Bert','Bloggs','something','something else','xxx','xxxx'),
        ('Mr','Charlie','Bloggs','something','something else','xxx','xxxx'),
        ('Mr','Dave','Bloggs','something','something else','xxx','xxxx'),
        ('Mr','Eddie','Bloggs','something','something else','xxx','xxxx'),
        ('Mr','Fred','Bloggs','something','something else','xxx','xxxx'),
        ('Mr','George','Bloggs','something','something else','xxx','xxxx')
    ;
    
SELECT * FROM Anuncio_empregador;

INSERT INTO Anuncio
    (USER_ID, Anuncio_perfil,Anuncio_empregado_info_ID,ANUNCIO_PRESTADOR_ID)
    VALUES
        (1,'empregador',1,100),
        (2,'empregador',2,100),
        (3,'empregador',3,100),
        (4,'not an empregador',1,100),
        (5,'not an empregador',2,100),
        (6,'not an empregador',3,100)
    ;
    
SELECT * FROM Anuncio;

SELECT * FROM Anuncio WHERE Anuncio_perfil = 'empregador';
                            
SELECT ID,Imagem_anuncio,Titulo,Descricao,Cidade
FROM Anuncio_empregador
WHERE ID IN 
    (
        SELECT Anuncio_empregado_info_ID 
        FROM ANUNCIO 
        WHERE ANUNCIO_PERFIL = 'empregador' AND USER_ID = user_id
        )
;
```

- Note that some liberties were taken, like

  - using the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and
  - using X'00010203040506070809'
- saving having to repeat these values which would have no impact upon workings of the SQL.

The resultant **Anuncio_empregador** table being :-

[image]

The resultant **Anuncio** table being :-

[image]

- i.e. last 3 rows  have been set to be excluded according to the clause `WHERE ANUNCIO_PERFIL = 'empregador'`

#### The result of the query in Question

```
SELECT ID,Imagem_anuncio,Titulo,Descricao,Cidade
FROM Anuncio_empregador
WHERE ID IN 
    (
        SELECT Anuncio_empregado_info_ID 
        FROM ANUNCIO 
        WHERE ANUNCIO_PERFIL = 'empregador' AND USER_ID = user_id
        )
;
```

being :-

[image]

- Note changing `AND USER_ID = user_id` to `AND USER_ID = 2` shows just the 1 row for Bert, as expected.